# Uppercase precedence in pandas column name assignment

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a reason why column name assignment in Pandas favours Uppercase over lower case?

Example:

```
dframe = DataFrame({'city':['Alma','Brian Head', 'Fox Park'],
                    'altitude':[3158,3000,2762]})
```

returns a DataFrame with columns in the order altitude, city.

Whereas:

```
dframe = DataFrame({'City':['Alma','Brian Head', 'Fox Park'],
                    'altitude':[3158,3000,2762]})
```

returns a DataFrame with columns in the order City,altitude.

Is this pandas specific or general python behaviour?

Comment: You're passing a dict so the key order is not necessarily the same order as they're declared no?

Comment: This is general python behaviour. You can try to sort a list with these names to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't actually ask this, but I'm assuming there is an implied question about how to preserve the original ordering?  If so, here are three ways:

1) Same basic dictionary constructor, but wrap in `collections.OrderedDict` (thanks to @shx2 for the correction):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
df1 = pd.DataFrame( OrderedDict([ ('city',['Alma','Brian Head', 'Fox Park']),
                                  ('altitude',[3158,3000,2762]) ]))
```

2) Non-dictionary constructor where you specifiy data array and column names separately, however, this essentially requires a row-centric entry rather than column-centric as with the dictionary constructor:

```
lst = [['Alma','Brian Head','Fox Park'],
       [3158,3000,2762]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame( map(list, zip(*lst)),
                    columns = ['city','altitude'] )
```

3) Simplest way is probably just to specify the order after you create the dataframe (thanks to @EdChum for catching the error in the original post):

```
df3 = df[['city','altitude']]
```

Test that results are the same for all three:

```
In [149]: all(df1==df2)
Out[149]: True

In [150]: all(df1==df3)
Out[150]: True
```

Comment: Won't the last one rename the columns as opposed to reorder them? you want `df.ix[:, ['city','altitude']]` to reorder them

Comment: or you can do `df = df[['city','altitude']]`

Comment: Yeah, the second way is what I intended to do originally.  Fixed now, thanks much!

Comment: passing a dict when creating an `OrderedDict` beats the purpose of the `OrderedDict`...

Comment: @shx2 Fixed now, thanks very much for the correction.